# Layer definition as "not editable" - INPUT app

Tags: layers, editing, mergin-maps

I am using QGIS 3.18. I have add two layers into my project. I have uploaded it to the INPUT app.
How can I define that one of the layers could **not** be editable in the app.

Answer (score 1):

I have got it! I  just need to define the layer as read only. That is the solution.

Comment: To add a little more detail to the correct answer by YuvalM, setting a layer's status is done via *Project Properties > Data Sources* and check the appropriate *Read Only* box.